# Complex structures compatible with a symplectic toric manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, toric-varieties

Let $(M^{2m},\omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold with equipped with an effective Hamiltonian torus $\mathbb T^m$ action.

Suppose $J_0$ and $J_1$ are two $\mathbb T^m$-invariant compatible complex structures on $M$. Can we prove that there exists a $\mathbb T^m$-equivariant diffeomorphism $\phi$ of $M$ such that

(1) $\phi^* J_1=J_0$;

(2) $\omega$ and $\phi^* \omega$ are in the same cohomology class.